# why are some Email Ids Getting accepted and some not PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have written This PHP code to for a login and a register page but, I don't know how it doesn't seem logical but it's not accepting some email it's while its accepting others. I don't know how is this even possible. I don't think is the apache server that I'm using because It wouldn't have accepted the other mails it accepted, I also tried restarting the server, Trying a different browser, I tried all that is to try. Please help.

```html
<?php 
session_start();
require_once "connect.php"
$con=@new mysqli($hn,$un,$pw,$db);
if($con->connect_error) die("Failed to connect to the database");

if (isset($_POST['register'])) 
{
 $nam=$_POST['name'];
 $sur=$_POST['sur'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $pass=$_POST['pass'];
 $cpass=$_POST['cpass'];
 if ($nam!="" && $sur!="" && $email!="" && $pass!="" && $cpass!="") 
 {
 if ($pass==$cpass) 
 {
 $userinfo=sanitise($nam,$sur,$email,$pass);
 if (validate($userinfo[0],$userinfo[1],$userinfo[2],$userinfo[3])) 
 {
  if(dataentry($userinfo[0],$userinfo[1],$userinfo[2],$userinfo[3]))
  {
  echo "Account Create Successfully";
  }
  else
  {
  echo "Failed to Create the account, Please try again After Some Time";
  }
  }
  }
 else
 {
  echo "The Entered Password do not Match";
 }
 }
 else
 {
  echo "Please fill all the fields";
 }
}
if (isset($_POST['login'])) 
{
 
 $id=$_POST['email'];
 $pin=$_POST['lpass'];
 $id=ucfirst(strtolower(stripslashes(strip_tags(htmlentities($id)))));
 $pin=stripcslashes(strip_tags(htmlentities($pin)));
 $pin=hash('ripemd128', $pin);
 if (isuser($id)) 
 {
  if (verify($id,$pin)) 
  {
   $_SESSION['email']=$id;
   header("Location:homepage.php");
  }
  else
  {
   echo "The Password And Email Do not Match";
  }
 }
 else
 {
  echo "The Email Id is Not Registered";
 }
}
function verify($email,$pass)
{
 global $con;
 $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$pass'";
 $result=$con->query($query);
 $rows=$result->num_rows;
 if ($rows==1) 
 {
  return 1;
 }
 else
 {
  return 0;
 }
}
function isuser($email)
{
 global $con;
 $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email='$email'";
 $result=$con->query($query);
 $rows=$result->num_rows;
 if ($rows==1) 
 {
  return 1;
 }
 else
 {
  return 0;
 }
}


function sanitise($name,$surname,$email,$password)
{

 $name=ucfirst(strtolower(stripslashes(strip_tags(htmlentities($name)))));
 $surname=ucfirst(strtolower(stripslashes(strip_tags(htmlentities($surname)))));
 $email=ucfirst(strtolower(stripslashes(strip_tags(htmlentities($email)))));
 $password=stripcslashes(strip_tags(htmlentities($password)));
 $password=hash('ripemd128',$password);
 return array($name,$surname,$email,$password);
}
function validate($name,$surname,$email,$password)
{
 global $con;
 $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
 $result=$con->query($query);
 $rows=$result->num_rows;
 if ($rows==0) 
 {
  return 1;
 }
 else
 {
  echo "Email Address is already in use";
 }
}
function dataentry($name,$surname,$email,$password)
{
 global $con;
 $query="INSERT INTO users (Name,Surname,Email,Password) VALUES ('$name','$surname','$email','$password')";
 $result=$con->query($query);
 if ($result) 
 {
  return 1;
 }
 else
 {
  return 0;
 }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: FYI, if I'm reading this code right, you have *major* SQL injection vulnerabilities in this code.

Comment: How do you suggest that I do it?

Comment: Read and understand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection and why it's so dangerous, then look into prepared statements / parameterized queries. https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared

Comment: Don't try to escape input, use prepared statements.

Comment: As everyone has said, use parameterized queries, the libraries supporting them are built to account for every possible thing a developer (_that does not have the time to dedicate to such a specific task, even if they do have the ability_) could overlook; for example, I see nothing in the code that even addresses the non-malicious scenario of names like `O'Brian`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hey there is no Reason for some email Ids to get accepted and some not, try restarting your apache server that might help.
Also read more about SQL Injection, I know you must be working locally and not deploying this, but still its good to know about it.Peace